# If statements in AnimationTimer that's in a for-each loop

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to create a game where every time when the play-controlled circle intersects with the "enemy" sprites, there will be a Label shown next to the circle that says "ouch"

```
Label ouch = new Label("ouch");
        pane.getChildren().add(ouch);

        for(StackPane s:sprites){
            new AnimationTimer(){
                double speed = (Math.random()*1 +.1 );
                double dx = speed * Math.cos(Math.random()*5 +1);
                double dy = speed * Math.sin(Math.random()*5 +1);
                @Override
                public void handle(long now){
                    s.setLayoutX(s.getLayoutX()+dx);
                    Bounds bounds = pane.getLayoutBounds();
                    s.setLayoutY(s.getLayoutY()+dy);                
                    if((s.getLayoutX() <=(bounds.getMinX()))|| (s.getLayoutX() + s.getWidth() >=(bounds.getMaxX()))){
                        dx = -dx;
                    }
                    if((s.getLayoutY() -10 <=(bounds.getMinY())) || (s.getLayoutY() + s.getHeight() +10 >=(bounds.getMaxY()))){
                        dy = -dy;
                    }
                    if(c.getBoundsInParent().intersects(s.getBoundsInParent())){
                        ouch.setVisible(true);
                        ouch.setTranslateX(c.getTranslateX());
                        ouch.setTranslateY(c.getTranslateY()+c.getRadius()+20);

                    }
                    else{ouch.setVisible(false);}
                }
            }.start();
        }
```

Here's the full code if needed:

```
import java.util.Random;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.scene.shape.CubicCurve;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.shape.Arc;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.shape.StrokeType;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;

public class Game extends Application{
    Stage window;

    Text bottomText = new Text();
    private final Integer startTime = 10;
    private Integer seconds = startTime;
    private Integer score = 30;
    
    @Override   
    public void start(Stage PrimaryStage){
        
                
        Image mouse = new Image("C:\\Users\\1559990\\Desktop\\images\\mouse.jpg");
        ImageView image = new ImageView(mouse);
        Label label = new Label("Times up!");
        Label label2 = new Label("Your score is: " + score);
        VBox vbox = new VBox(20);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(image,label,label2);
        vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);      
        Scene scene2 = new Scene(vbox,600,600);
        
        Color yaleBlue = Color.web("154179");
        Color lightBlue = Color.web("9FC2CC");
        
        window = PrimaryStage;
        window.setTitle("Game");
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        
        bottomText.setFont(Font.font("Calibri",FontWeight.BOLD,100));
        bottomText.setFill(lightBlue);
        //bottomText.setStrokeWidth(2);
        //bottomText.setStroke(lightBlue);
        //bottomText.setStrokeType(StrokeType.OUTSIDE);
        bottomText.setText(startTime.toString());
        
        Text topText = new Text("GAME");
        topText.setFont(Font.font("Arial",FontWeight.BOLD,50));
        topText.setFill(yaleBlue);
        topText.setStrokeWidth(1);
        topText.setStroke(lightBlue);
        topText.setStrokeType(StrokeType.OUTSIDE);
        
        //borderPane.setBottom(bottomText);
        borderPane.setAlignment(bottomText,Pos.CENTER);
        borderPane.setTop(topText);
        borderPane.setAlignment(topText,Pos.CENTER);
        borderPane.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));

        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane,600,600);
        window.setScene(scene);
        Pane pane = new Pane();

        ArrayList<StackPane> sprites = new ArrayList<StackPane>();
        String[] browTypes = new String[]{"angry","sad","normal"};
        
        for(int i = 0;i<=5;i++){
            Color randomColor = Color.rgb((int)(Math.random()*255),(int)(Math.random()*255),(int)(Math.random()*255));  
            int browIndex = (int)(Math.random()*2+1);
            StackPane sprite = new Human(randomColor,0.7,browTypes[browIndex]).getBody();
            sprites.add(sprite);
        }
        
        StackPane sp = new StackPane();
        for(StackPane s:sprites){
            pane.getChildren().addAll(s);
            s.relocate(250,250);
        }
        sp.getChildren().addAll(bottomText,pane);
        
        borderPane.setCenter(sp);
        borderPane.setMaxSize(600,100);
        
        
        //moving
        ArrayList<String> allKeyPressed = new ArrayList<String>();
        Circle c = new Circle(10);
        pane.getChildren().add(c);
        
        //add up/left/right/down from allKeyPressed
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event){
                if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.W){
                    if(!(hasMultiple(allKeyPressed,"up"))){
                        allKeyPressed.add("up");
                    }
                }
                if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.A){
                    if(!(hasMultiple(allKeyPressed,"left"))){
                        allKeyPressed.add("left");
                    }
                }
                if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.S){
                    if(!(hasMultiple(allKeyPressed,"down"))){
                        allKeyPressed.add("down");
                    }
                }
                if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.D){
                    if(!(hasMultiple(allKeyPressed,"right"))){
                        allKeyPressed.add("right");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        
        //remove up/left/right/down from allKeyPressed
        scene.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event){
                if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.W){
                    if(hasMultiple(allKeyPressed,"up")){
                        allKeyPressed.remove(getIndex(allKeyPressed,"up"));
                    }
                }
                if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.A){
                    if(hasMultiple(allKeyPressed,"left")){
                        allKeyPressed.remove(getIndex(allKeyPressed,"left"));
                    }
                }
                if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.S){
                    if(hasMultiple(allKeyPressed,"down")){
                        allKeyPressed.remove(getIndex(allKeyPressed,"down"));
                    }
                }
                if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.D){
                    if(hasMultiple(allKeyPressed,"right")){
                        allKeyPressed.remove(getIndex(allKeyPressed,"right"));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        
        //moving
        new AnimationTimer(){
            Bounds bounds = borderPane.getBoundsInLocal();
            @Override
            public void handle(long how){
                if(hasMultiple(allKeyPressed,"up") && (c.getTranslateY() - c.getRadius() -100>= bounds.getMinY())){
                    c.setTranslateY(c.getTranslateY()-5 );
                }
                if(hasMultiple(allKeyPressed,"down") && (c.getTranslateY() + c.getRadius()<= bounds.getMaxY()-80)){
                    c.setTranslateY(c.getTranslateY()+5);
                }
                if(hasMultiple(allKeyPressed,"left") && (c.getTranslateX() >= bounds.getMinX() + 20)){
                    c.setTranslateX(c.getTranslateX()-5);
                }
                if(hasMultiple(allKeyPressed,"right") && (c.getTranslateX() <= bounds.getMaxX()-40)){
                    c.setTranslateX(c.getTranslateX()+5);
                }
            }
        }.start();
        
        Label ouch = new Label("ouch");
        pane.getChildren().add(ouch);

        for(StackPane s:sprites){
            new AnimationTimer(){
                double speed = (Math.random()*1 +.1 );
                double dx = speed * Math.cos(Math.random()*5 +1);
                double dy = speed * Math.sin(Math.random()*5 +1);
                @Override
                public void handle(long now){
                    s.setLayoutX(s.getLayoutX()+dx);
                    Bounds bounds = pane.getLayoutBounds();
                    s.setLayoutY(s.getLayoutY()+dy);                
                    if((s.getLayoutX() <=(bounds.getMinX()))|| (s.getLayoutX() + s.getWidth() >=(bounds.getMaxX()))){
                        dx = -dx;
                    }
                    if((s.getLayoutY() -10 <=(bounds.getMinY())) || (s.getLayoutY() + s.getHeight() +10 >=(bounds.getMaxY()))){
                        dy = -dy;
                    }
                    if(c.getBoundsInParent().intersects(s.getBoundsInParent())){
                        ouch.setVisible(true);
                        ouch.setTranslateX(c.getTranslateX());
                        ouch.setTranslateY(c.getTranslateY()+c.getRadius()+20);

                    }
                    else{ouch.setVisible(false);}
                }
            }.start();
        }
        
        
        Timeline time = new Timeline();
        time.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        if(time != null){
            time.stop();
        }
        KeyFrame frame = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1),new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event){
                seconds--;
                bottomText.setText(seconds.toString());
                if(seconds<=0){
                    time.stop();
                    //window.setScene(scene2);
                }
            }
        });
        time.getKeyFrames().add(frame);
        time.playFromStart();

        
        window.show();


    }

    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
    //helper detect if up/left/down/right is in allKeyPressed
    private boolean hasMultiple(ArrayList<String> keys,String arrow){
        for(String s:keys){
            if(s.equals(arrow)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    //help to know the index where the w/s/a/d is at in the allKeyPressed
    private int getIndex(ArrayList<String>keys,String arrow){
        for(int i = 0; i<keys.size();i++){
            if(keys.get(i).equals(arrow)){
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

}
```

What I had in mind was setting if-statements in the AnimationTimer, so if the bounds of the circle intersect with the bounds with one of the enemy sprites, the "ouch" text will be set visible. And if they are not intersecting, the "ouch" text will not be shown
However, my problem is that this effect will happen for only ONE of the many sprites and not the others. I tested my condition if(bounds of circle intersects bounds of sprite) by having the system print out some random text, and my conditions seem to be since things indeed got printed when the circle and the sprite intersects.
I'm really confuse and will appreciate any help

Comment: Having a quick read of your code, it seems that you only have one "ouch" label, which is being being either toggled on or toggled off.

Comment: I would do this another way, e.g. maintain an observable list of sprites and loop through them in an update routine you write in a single animation timer.  After the update you can check for collisions.  Like [in this example](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/910dae32ef6d1bd4257850031aefcba2).  Perhaps that is just personal preference though.

Comment: If you do want to use one `AnimationTimer` for each object that is moving, you can leverage the fact that each one’s `handle(…)` method will be called with the same timestamp in a given rendering frame. It’s probably easier to use a single timer though.

Comment: You will probably get more complete help if you create and post a [mre]. Create an application has nothing irrelevant: No controls or nodes that are not relevant to the problem. You probably don't need the user to be able to move anything around to demonstrate the problem. Don't use image files, either use shapes instead or create an image on the fly with either data urls or by creating very simple `WritableImage` instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly I agree to all suggestions provided in the comments. Please try to consider those suggestions.

> However, my problem is that this effect will happen for only ONE of
> the many sprites and not the others.

Please note that the ***ONE of many sprites*** is always the last sprite in your sprites list ;).

Coming to the issue, the main reason for "Ouch" `Label` to display on only the last sprite but not the others is because of the way how you included the code of `AnimationTimer`s in the for loop.

All the timers will be executed sequentially and the check for overlap is happening independently in its own timer. So, lets say Sprite1 intersects with Circle and turn the Label visibility to `true`, the next check in the remaining sprite timers will turn the visibility to `false` (when they are not overlapped). Which is why, only the last Sprite is working effectively, as there is no other further sprite check happening (to turn it OFF) :)

**Solution:**

One way to fix this is by checking the overlap check on all sprites at once and then decide the Label visibility if atleast one sprite is overlapped.

So we can optimise the code to have the for loop using only one AnimationTimer for overlap checking. Something like:

```
new AnimationTimer() {
    double speed = (Math.random() * 1 + .1);
    double dx = speed * Math.cos(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
    double dy = speed * Math.sin(Math.random() * 5 + 1);

    @Override
    public void handle(long now) {
        boolean intersected = false;
        for (StackPane s : sprites) {

            // YOUR LOGIC OF MOVING THE SPRITES HERE

            if (c.getBoundsInParent().intersects(s.getBoundsInParent())) {
                intersected = true;
            }
        }
        if(intersected){
            ouch.setVisible(true);
            ouch.setTranslateX(c.getTranslateX());
            ouch.setTranslateY(c.getTranslateY() + c.getRadius() + 20);
        } else {
            ouch.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}.start();
```

But there is one problem with the above code. All the sprites will have the same speed or position calculations. So to fix this, we can move this logic in its own class (for each sprite) and then we do the overlap checking.

```
// First create each separate move service for each sprite.
List<SpriteService> spriteServices = sprites.stream().map(sprite -> new SpriteService(sprite, pane)).collect(Collectors.toList());

new AnimationTimer() {
    @Override
    public void handle(long now) {
        boolean intersected = false;
        for (SpriteService spriteService : spriteServices) {
            spriteService.move();
            if (c.getBoundsInParent().intersects(spriteService.getSprite().getBoundsInParent())) {
                intersected = true;
            }
        }
        if (intersected) {
            ouch.setVisible(true);
            ouch.setTranslateX(c.getTranslateX());
            ouch.setTranslateY(c.getTranslateY() + c.getRadius() + 20);
        } else {
            ouch.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}.start();

class SpriteService {
    double speed = (Math.random() * 1 + .1);
    double dx = speed * Math.cos(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
    double dy = speed * Math.sin(Math.random() * 5 + 1);

    StackPane s;
    Pane pane;

    public SpriteService(StackPane sp, Pane p) {
        s = sp;
        pane = p;
    }

    public void move() {
        s.setLayoutX(s.getLayoutX() + dx);
        s.setLayoutY(s.getLayoutY() + dy);
        Bounds bounds = pane.getLayoutBounds();
        if ((s.getLayoutX() <= (bounds.getMinX())) || (s.getLayoutX() + s.getWidth() >= (bounds.getMaxX()))) {
            dx = -dx;
        }
        if ((s.getLayoutY() - 10 <= (bounds.getMinY())) || (s.getLayoutY() + s.getHeight() + 10 >= (bounds.getMaxY()))) {
            dy = -dy;
        }
    }

    public StackPane getSprite() {
        return s;
    }
}
```

Below is a quick demo of your code using the above approach. ***Note that there is lot of scope for optimizing/refactoring your code. I have not considered changing that as it is not relevant for this question.***

[image]

```
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.StrokeType;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Game extends Application {
    Stage window;

    Text bottomText = new Text();
    private final Integer startTime = 10;
    private Integer seconds = startTime;
    private Integer score = 30;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage PrimaryStage) throws MalformedURLException {
        Label label = new Label("Times up!");
        Label label2 = new Label("Your score is: " + score);
        VBox vbox = new VBox(20);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, label2);
        vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Color yaleBlue = Color.web("154179");
        Color lightBlue = Color.web("9FC2CC");

        window = PrimaryStage;
        window.setTitle("Game");
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();

        bottomText.setFont(Font.font("Calibri", FontWeight.BOLD, 100));
        bottomText.setFill(lightBlue);
        bottomText.setText(startTime.toString());

        Text topText = new Text("GAME");
        topText.setFont(Font.font("Arial", FontWeight.BOLD, 50));
        topText.setFill(yaleBlue);
        topText.setStrokeWidth(1);
        topText.setStroke(lightBlue);
        topText.setStrokeType(StrokeType.OUTSIDE);

        borderPane.setAlignment(bottomText, Pos.CENTER);
        borderPane.setTop(topText);
        borderPane.setAlignment(topText, Pos.CENTER);
        borderPane.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));

        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 600, 600);
        window.setScene(scene);
        Pane pane = new Pane();

        List<StackPane> sprites = new ArrayList<StackPane>();
        String[] browTypes = new String[]{"angry", "sad", "normal"};

        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            Color randomColor = Color.rgb((int) (Math.random() * 255), (int) (Math.random() * 255), (int) (Math.random() * 255));
            int browIndex = (int) (Math.random() * 2 + 1);
            StackPane sprite = new Human(randomColor, 0.7, browTypes[browIndex], i).getBody();
            sprites.add(sprite);
        }

        StackPane sp = new StackPane();
        for (StackPane s : sprites) {
            pane.getChildren().addAll(s);
            s.relocate(250, 250);
        }
        sp.getChildren().addAll(bottomText, pane);

        borderPane.setCenter(sp);
        borderPane.setMaxSize(600, 100);


        //moving
        ArrayList<String> allKeyPressed = new ArrayList<String>();
        Circle c = new Circle(10);
        pane.getChildren().add(c);

        //add up/left/right/down from allKeyPressed
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.W) {
                if (!(hasMultiple(allKeyPressed, "up"))) {
                    allKeyPressed.add("up");
                }
            }
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.A) {
                if (!(hasMultiple(allKeyPressed, "left"))) {
                    allKeyPressed.add("left");
                }
            }
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.S) {
                if (!(hasMultiple(allKeyPressed, "down"))) {
                    allKeyPressed.add("down");
                }
            }
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.D) {
                if (!(hasMultiple(allKeyPressed, "right"))) {
                    allKeyPressed.add("right");
                }
            }
        });

        //remove up/left/right/down from allKeyPressed
        scene.setOnKeyReleased(event -> {
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.W) {
                if (hasMultiple(allKeyPressed, "up")) {
                    allKeyPressed.remove(getIndex(allKeyPressed, "up"));
                }
            }
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.A) {
                if (hasMultiple(allKeyPressed, "left")) {
                    allKeyPressed.remove(getIndex(allKeyPressed, "left"));
                }
            }
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.S) {
                if (hasMultiple(allKeyPressed, "down")) {
                    allKeyPressed.remove(getIndex(allKeyPressed, "down"));
                }
            }
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.D) {
                if (hasMultiple(allKeyPressed, "right")) {
                    allKeyPressed.remove(getIndex(allKeyPressed, "right"));
                }
            }
        });

        //moving
        new AnimationTimer() {
            Bounds bounds = borderPane.getBoundsInLocal();

            @Override
            public void handle(long how) {
                if (hasMultiple(allKeyPressed, "up") && (c.getTranslateY() - c.getRadius() - 100 >= bounds.getMinY())) {
                    c.setTranslateY(c.getTranslateY() - 5);
                }
                if (hasMultiple(allKeyPressed, "down") && (c.getTranslateY() + c.getRadius() <= bounds.getMaxY() - 80)) {
                    c.setTranslateY(c.getTranslateY() + 5);
                }
                if (hasMultiple(allKeyPressed, "left") && (c.getTranslateX() >= bounds.getMinX() + 20)) {
                    c.setTranslateX(c.getTranslateX() - 5);
                }
                if (hasMultiple(allKeyPressed, "right") && (c.getTranslateX() <= bounds.getMaxX() - 40)) {
                    c.setTranslateX(c.getTranslateX() + 5);
                }
            }
        }.start();

        Label ouch = new Label("ouch");
        pane.getChildren().add(ouch);

        // previousAnimationTimer(sprites, pane, c, ouch);
        modifiedAnimationTimer(sprites, pane, c, ouch);

        Timeline time = new Timeline();
        time.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        if (time != null) {
            time.stop();
        }
        KeyFrame frame = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                seconds--;
                bottomText.setText(seconds.toString());
                if (seconds <= 0) {
                    time.stop();
                    //window.setScene(scene2);
                }
            }
        });
        time.getKeyFrames().add(frame);
        time.playFromStart();
        window.show();
    }


    private void previousAnimationTimer(List<StackPane> sprites, Pane pane, Circle c, Label ouch) {
        for (StackPane s : sprites) {
            new AnimationTimer() {
                double speed = (Math.random() * 1 + .1);
                double dx = speed * Math.cos(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
                double dy = speed * Math.sin(Math.random() * 5 + 1);

                @Override
                public void handle(long now) {
                    s.setLayoutX(s.getLayoutX() + dx);
                    Bounds bounds = pane.getLayoutBounds();
                    s.setLayoutY(s.getLayoutY() + dy);
                    if ((s.getLayoutX() <= (bounds.getMinX())) || (s.getLayoutX() + s.getWidth() >= (bounds.getMaxX()))) {
                        dx = -dx;
                    }
                    if ((s.getLayoutY() - 10 <= (bounds.getMinY())) || (s.getLayoutY() + s.getHeight() + 10 >= (bounds.getMaxY()))) {
                        dy = -dy;
                    }
                    if (c.getBoundsInParent().intersects(s.getBoundsInParent())) {
                        ouch.setVisible(true);
                        ouch.setTranslateX(c.getTranslateX());
                        ouch.setTranslateY(c.getTranslateY() + c.getRadius() + 20);
                    } else {
                        ouch.setVisible(false);
                    }
                }
            }.start();
        }
    }

    private void modifiedAnimationTimer(List<StackPane> sprites, Pane pane, Circle c, Label ouch) {
        // First create each separate move service for each sprite.
        List<SpriteService> spriteServices = sprites.stream().map(sprite -> new SpriteService(sprite, pane)).collect(Collectors.toList());

        new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                boolean intersected = false;
                for (SpriteService spriteService : spriteServices) {
                    spriteService.move();
                    if (c.getBoundsInParent().intersects(spriteService.getSprite().getBoundsInParent())) {
                        intersected = true;
                    }
                }
                if (intersected) {
                    ouch.setVisible(true);
                    ouch.setTranslateX(c.getTranslateX());
                    ouch.setTranslateY(c.getTranslateY() + c.getRadius() + 20);
                } else {
                    ouch.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    //helper detect if up/left/down/right is in allKeyPressed
    private boolean hasMultiple(ArrayList<String> keys, String arrow) {
        for (String s : keys) {
            if (s.equals(arrow)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    //help to know the index where the w/s/a/d is at in the allKeyPressed
    private int getIndex(ArrayList<String> keys, String arrow) {
        for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
            if (keys.get(i).equals(arrow)) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    class Human {
        Color c;
        int id;

        public Human(Color randomColor, double v, String browType, int i) {
            c = randomColor;
            id = i;
        }

        public StackPane getBody() {
            StackPane sp = new StackPane(new Label(id + ""));
            sp.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(c, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
            sp.setMinSize(25, 25);
            sp.setMaxSize(25, 25);
            return sp;
        }
    }

    class SpriteService {
        private double speed = (Math.random() * 1 + .1);
        private double dx = speed * Math.cos(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
        private double dy = speed * Math.sin(Math.random() * 5 + 1);

        private StackPane s;
        private Pane pane;

        public SpriteService(StackPane sp, Pane p) {
            s = sp;
            pane = p;
        }

        public void move() {
            s.setLayoutX(s.getLayoutX() + dx);
            s.setLayoutY(s.getLayoutY() + dy);
            Bounds bounds = pane.getLayoutBounds();
            if ((s.getLayoutX() <= (bounds.getMinX())) || (s.getLayoutX() + s.getWidth() >= (bounds.getMaxX()))) {
                dx = -dx;
            }
            if ((s.getLayoutY() - 10 <= (bounds.getMinY())) || (s.getLayoutY() + s.getHeight() + 10 >= (bounds.getMaxY()))) {
                dy = -dy;
            }
        }

        public StackPane getSprite() {
            return s;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation!! I had spent two days on this problem and your explanation really helped a lot! :) Thank you!